# Just one class object works

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm trying to make a collision that avoid player to move for a direction by hitting any side from the class `wall` children.

If I add more than one child of `wall`, it will be added on stage, but just one from the children gets the class commands block (code).

---

What I'm doing in...

Timeline

```
var canplayerMoveToTop = true;
var canplayerMoveToBottom = true;
var canplayerMoveToLeft = true;
var canplayerToRight = true;

function addPlayerToStage(playerX, playerY) {
    var addingPlayerTo:player = new player(playerX, playerY);
    addChild(addingPlayerTo);
    return addingPlayerTo;
}

var playerOn = addPlayerToStage(25, 35);

function addWall(XChoosen, YChoosen) {
    var addingWall:testWall = new testWall();
    addingWall.x = XChoosen; addingWall.y = YChoosen;
    addChild(addingWall);
    return addingWall;
}

var myNewWall = addWall(155, 55);
var anotherWall = addWall(355, 55);
```

Wall

```
package  {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class testWall extends MovieClip {

        public function testWall() {
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, whenWasThisWallAdded);
        }
        public function whenWasThisWallAdded(e:Event):void {
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, checkAndUpdateGround);
        }
        public function checkAndUpdateGround(e:Event):void {
            if (this.bottomC.hitTestObject(MovieClip(root).playerOn)) {
                parent['canplayerMoveToTop'] = false;
            }
            else if (this.topC.hitTestObject(MovieClip(root).playerOn)) {
                parent['canplayerMoveToBottom'] = false;
            }
            else if (this.leftC.hitTestObject(MovieClip(root).playerOn)) {
                parent['canplayerToRight'] = false;
            }
            else if (this.rightC.hitTestObject(MovieClip(root).playerOn)) {
                parent['canplayerMoveToLeft'] = false;
            }
            else {
                parent['canplayerMoveToTop'] = true;
                parent['canplayerMoveToBottom'] = true;
                parent['canplayerMoveToLeft'] = true;
                parent['canplayerToRight'] = true;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean with `but only ONE of this child get the functions of the class` ? Please explain with more detail.

Comment: Oh! Sorry... I'm adding more than 1 testWall (obj), but only ONE get the class functions, actions, etc. Did you get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of the problem is the poor separation of concerns and lack of encapsulation.

### separation of concerns

Your class `Wall` (`testWall` is a bad name for a class, they should start with a capital name and prepending "test" is kind of pointless, because during development, you are always testing) is doing too much (separation of concerns).

It not only does a `hitTest`, but also sets some variables of some other object, namely `canplayerMoveToLeft` etc. It shouldn't do that. This is the problem in your design.

Think about it this way: the regular `hitTestObject` only returns true or false. It doesn't set any variables to true or false. That makes it very flexible and more universally useful.

You broke that by not simply returning a value, but instead setting variables. It's the difference between offering somebody something and forcing them to take it. You are doing the latter. In order to do this, the Wall class has to deal with variables that it shouldn't deal with.

### encapsulation

Using dynamic property access to get to variables is usually a bad idea.
In your case, both objects are accessing the same variables which leads to a mess, because they are overwriting the results of each other.
These 4 variables are clearly related to the `Player` (as I said, classes should start with capital letters). That's why they should be part of that class and not floating around as individual variables.

### solution Player class

Add all the 4 variables that define if the player can move in a direction to the `Player` class. The below example code shows 1 such variable. Note how this makes it unnecessary to include the player in the name of the variable

```
package  
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    private movableTop:Boolean = true;

    public class Player extends Sprite 
    {
        public function set canMoveToTop(value:Boolean):void
        {
            movableTop = value;
        }
    } 
}
```

No, it is not recommended to bloat the constructor with parameters like `x` and `y`. If you want to set those properties, do it like you did with the `Wall` class: set those properties separately.

Furthermore, add a method `reset` for convenience that sets all the 4 variables back to true;

### solution Wall class

The `Wall` class should only provide a functionality for `hitTest`ing against the `Player`. Again, look at how the built in As3 API works, `hitTestObject` doesn't run every frame on its own with some arbitrary object. Instead, you have to explicitly call the function and pass the object as a parameter. The simplified `Wall` could look something like this:

```
package  
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class Wall extends Sprite 
    {
        public function hitTestPlayer(player:Player):void 
        {
            if(bottomC.hitTestObject(player)) 
            {
                player.canMoveToTop = false;
            }
            else if(topC.hitTestObject(player)) 
            {
                player.canMoveToBottom = false;
            }
            else if(leftC.hitTestObject(player) 
            {
                player.canMoveToRight = false;
            }
            else if(rightC.hitTestObject(player) 
            {
                player.canMoveToLeft = false;
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Because the player object is passed to the function it is valid to change variables in the `hitTest` function. As an alternative, you could return a value that represents the result of all the `hitTest`ing

### solution Main class formerly known as Timeline

Don't put code on the timeline. Use a document class, I call it `Main`. this is where the logic of repeatedly calling hitTests and other functions should be located.

```
package  
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {
        private var player:Player;
        private var walls:Array = [];

        public function Main():void 
        {
            player = addPlayerAt(25, 35);

            addWallAt(155, 55);
            addWallAt(355, 55);

            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);
        }

        public function loop(e:Event):void
        {
            player.reset();

            for each(var wall:Wall in walls)
            {
                wall.hitTestPlayer(player);
            }
        }

        private function addPlayerAt(x:Number, y:Number):Player 
        {
            var player:Player = new Player();
            player.x = x; 
            player.y = y;
            addChild(player);
            return player;
        }

        private function addWallAt(x:Number, y:Number):Wall 
        {
            var wall:Wall = new Wall();
            wall.x = x; 
            wall.y = y;
            addChild(wall);
            walls.push(wall);
            return wall;
        }
    } 
}
```

Code untested, you get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Both walls are most likely getting the function, but since they both modify the same properties in the parent (`canplayerMoveToTop`, `canplayerMoveToBottom`, etc) you are only ever seeing the result of the last wall to run the `checkAndUpdateGround` function (it's overwriting the values that would have been set by the other walls.
You should be able to verify this with some trace statements.